# macos calendar duplicate repeated meetings from exchange

Tags: macos, calendar, exchange

Look at screenshot. There should be only one everyday meeting. But its looks like 7 parallel meetings. It's desplayed right in Outlook for Windows. Deleting meetings from MacOS Callendar don't help for feature days and I can't delete meeting and create new, because i'm not an initiator of this.

May be clearing some cashed data would help, but I don't know where to do this.
Deleting Exchange account from MacOs and creating new link don't help too :(

[image]